# Primary key generator for pydantic model with FastAPI?

Tags: mongodb, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to create objects with a primary integer key, but when using fastAPI, I cannot get the keys to autogenerate. The validator says an ID needs to be passed in to pass validation, which makes sense, but I want to instead have an autokey each time a new object is created. How does one do this?

```
class PinSchema(BaseModel): id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)

class PinSchema(BaseModel):
   id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)
   //some other fields here

class Config:
    allow_population_by_field_name = True
    arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```

This is my current model for the object. I set the int to optional, but now it just has the default as null, not the autogen int.

I tried to set the field as optional, but it just defaults to null even after I set the default to a primary key field. I also tried just leaving it as int = Field(primary_key=True), but no luck, it fails the validation. Is there a way to exclude the id field from the validation process with fastAPI?

Comment: Pydantic has _no way to know_ which keys have already been used. That would be the task for your database layer, and not for Pydantic.

Comment: This is not reproducible.